# Bootstrap CSS - nested column does not clear / placed outside block

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have a nested column using the bootstrap CSS grid.

This column sits outside my main area due to it being floated right, so the container isn't expanding to hold it. All the text in the example below should be inside `.property-item` which has a grey background.

### JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5jqsoacs/

I've looked into the [documentation](http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/css/#grid) which states there are some classes to help, but I can't get them to work. I've tried the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 no-gutter full-buffer clearfix"><p>£98 pp/pw</p></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 no-gutter full-buffer text-right clearfix"><p><span class="bedroom icon">4></span></p></div>
```

Adding `clearfix` to the column, but it makes no change, and my two columns still sit outside their wrapper.

Any advice?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? From your fiddle, it seems you are using classes which aren't there. Like `no-gutter` and  `full-buffer`.

Comment: @Abhitalks both of those classes don't matter for this problem. The issue is that the two bottom pieces of text (`£` and number) are floated, and the grey box is not accommodating them, despite the fact they are inside it. This seems to be an issue in Bootstrap but none of the fixes given work correctly. Whenever I nest a column, the container doesn't expand to contain it.

Comment: @Abhitalks I have updated my question to reflect what I am seeking. `.property-item` is not expanding to contain all it's elements. I'm looking for a specific bootstrap fix to this issue.

Comment: Bootstrap recommends wrapping your `col`s in `row`s even when nesting. I think that is where you got it broken. Also you missed the other `col-md-9` after your `col-md-3`. You have to complete a grid of 12 columns. See here - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5jqsoacs/1/

Comment: Also note that you are not floating anything, and so clearing is not required. This is the real documentation - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: So the only way to have nested columns is to make a row for absolutely everything? This removes all the padding laid out by the columns and makes Bootstrap utterly pointless.

Comment: @Abhitalks yes, it is being floated. Check the CSS. The nested columns have float:left

Comment: (1) *"So the only way to have nested columns is to make a row for absolutely everything"* - Well, you can have `col-xx-12` to mimic a row, but again it is recommended to wrap in `row`. (2) *"This removes all the padding laid out by the columns"* -- How so? (3) "*The nested columns have float:left*" -- Yes, but you need not to clear them. Bootstrap already does that for you provided you follow the structure of wrapping in `row`. (4) This is why I first asked, what you really want to do. Would it be possible for you to clarify that a little more?

Comment: _“Adding clearfix to the column, but it makes no change, and my two columns still sit outside their wrapper.”_ – if you want to have the container element wrapped around the floated children, you need to put `clearfix` on the container, not the children. https://jsfiddle.net/5jqsoacs/7/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot about .row class. You need to put exactly "12" columns into one row.
See this and you'll understand:

https://jsfiddle.net/5jqsoacs/6/

```
<div class="property-item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text">
                <h3>12 Fairholme Road</h3>
                <h4>Woolacombe</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 no-gutter full-buffer clearfix">
            <p>£98 pp/pw</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no-gutter full-buffer text-right clearfix">
            <p><span class="bedroom icon">4</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .property-item -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this code, its working well. hope it will resolve your issue.**

```
<div class="property-item clearfix">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="text container">
             <h3>12 Fairholme Road</h3>
             <h4>Woolacombe</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no-gutter full-buffer ">
            <p>£98 pp/pw</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no-gutter full-buffer text-right ">
            <p><span class="bedroom icon">4</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```